# Word for "Attempted Conversation"

Tags: single-word-requests

What would be a word to describe a person attempting to start a conversation?

For example,

> "What a nice necklace that is. Is that from Peru?" [word here]ed Henry.

Or...

> "I'm glad I finished this, the boss will sure be happy to see that it's done," [word here]ed George to his colleague.

It's not as obvious in the second case, but the word should denote that he's expecting a response.

Comment: If he's trying to get the attention of others in a small group that is already in conversation then I'd use "injected".

Comment: "What a nice necklace that is. Is that from Peru?" Henry asked (questioned). "I'm glad I finished this, the boss will surely be happy to see that it's done," George said (declared) to his colleague.

Comment: @HotLicks "injected", hmm? Doesn't it mean "to introduce with pressure"? When you inject a speech or a topic you do it the hard way. Force it in. Am I wrong on this one?

Comment: It's often used to mean wedging a few words into a conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like "suggested" (already suggested).  Also:

Lead with

Start

Begin

Try

Attempt

Comment: I think "attempt" is perfect.

Comment: @GeneralNuisance - glad it works for you.  I looked back at your question again, and "attempt" is right there at the beginning -- so I agree, it fits what you described!

Answer (score 1):

If the person in question is shy, you coud use *falter.* It means ["to utter hesitatingly or brokenly."](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/falter) *Stammer* is another possibility: ["To speak with many pauses and repetitions because you have a speech problem or because you are very nervous, frightened, etc."](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stammer)

The firs sentence could work with *stutter,* at least in my opinion. Another possibility is to add a description: "He said, hesitant..."

Answer (score 0):

Look here: http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/clause4b.html

- "**suggested**" - may be a good example, but i can't see how it could
  nicely fit in here.
- "**questioned**" - Is another good choice. It seems to fit in like a glove in the first sentence.
- "**posed**" - Is a possible variant. To set forth or offer for attention or consideration "Let me pose a question". http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pose

Another good list: http://www.killermovies.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-442947-words-to-replace-said.html

Answer (score 0):

[Interjected](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interject) meaning "to interrupt what someone else is saying with (a comment, remark, etc.)" could be a viable choice.

Comment: "What a nice necklace that is. Is that from Peru?" Henry interjected. - Sorry, but the last sentence in his speech is an interrogative one. Is it possible to use "interjected" with those? And it's an "interrupter word", so it interrupts a person who is attempting a conversation or is leading one.

Comment: “That's an interesting idea,” he interjected, “but I don't think you've considered all of the details.” from http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interject

Comment: @SovereignSun You can use 'interjected' with questions. Also, I believe you needn't be interrupting an existing conversation, it could be another activity, like a quiet game of chess, that the statement/question would be an interruption to.  It certainly isn't the right word in a lot of contexts, but starting off by asking about a necklace sounds like something that might be an interjection.

Comment: "What a nice necklace that is," he interjected. "Is that from Peru?" - it should like this then. I guess.